# How to parse /* based on contents within

Tags: bash, parsing, scripting

I have a file containing:

```
/*
  // iOS device address. Ensure 'appium' and 'ios_webkit_debug_proxy'
  // are running, and 'ignoreSynchronization' is true in utils
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub',
  capabilities: {
    browserName: '',
    platformName: 'iOS',
    platformVersion: '7.1',
    deviceName: 'iPhone',
    autoWebview: true
  },
*/

/*    
  // android device address. Ensure 'appium' and 'ios_webkit_debug_proxy'
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub',
  capabilities: {
    browserName: '',
    platformName: 'Android',
    platformVersion: '4.2.2',
    deviceName: 'Nexus',
    autoWebview: true
  },
*/
```

How can I parse the file to remove the comments only for iOS or android? Currently I only know how to remove /* */ by running:

```
sed 's/\/\*//'
sed 's/\*\///'
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to remove the commented block, or are you saying you want to uncomment the configuration elements that are commented using `/* ... */` ?

Comment: I'd like to uncomment android block or ios block /* ... */ based on an argument

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
sed -r 's|^\s+\/\/||'
```

Comment: Pretty sure that's not what he's asking for.

Answer (score 0):

If the `/*` and `*/` surrounding the blocks are always at the beginning of a line, the following little awk program should work:

```
awk -v MATCH="// android" '
  /^\*\//  { if (acc ~ MATCH) print acc "\n" $0; acc = ""; next}
  acc      { acc = acc "\n" $0; next }
  /^\/\*/  { acc = $0; next }
           { print}
' file.txt
```

`MATCH` needs to be set to a regex which describes what you are looking for inside the block. You can adjust the patterns which match the beginning and end of the block to be more precise.